# Counting polynomials which are constant on a specific hyperplane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Say a function $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}$ is having the *1-property* if it equals $1$ on the hyperplane $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i=1$.

How many polynomials of degree $n$ have the 1-property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infinitely many.  Anything of the form $g(x_1,\ldots,x_m) (\sum_{i=1}^m x_i - 1) + 1$ where $g$
has degree $n-1$ will do.

Answer (score 1):

Infinitely many. In particular, given any polynomial $f(x)$ we have that
$$f(x)\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^m x_i\right)+1$$
is such a polynomial, and this describes all such polynomials.